# How to know if the object is moving upward or downward?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a gameobject and I would like to find out if the object is moving upward (positive) or downward (negative). How do I get to do this?

Comment: I am not familiar with unity3d, but don't you have a velocity vector somewhere?

Comment: Please add more information. How far have you gotten yourself? Do you have a reference to your GameObject in code or do you just have it in your scene? Does your GameObject have a Rigidbody Component? How do you move your GameObject?

Comment: There is no code for this yet. Just an idea. No the gameObject does not contain any rigidbody, its movement is purely in the y axis direction and it follows the movement of another gameObject.

Comment: As there is not enough information, I can suggest you can check that with Y axis.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that the object has a rigidbody, you can use this in the update method (or anywhere for that matter) of a MonoBehavior attached to your GameObject.

```
Rigidbody rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
float verticalVelocity = rb.velocity.y;
```

If you want the velocity along *any* axis, you can use the dot product:

```
Rigidbody rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
Vector3 someAxisInWorldSpace = transform.forward;
float velocityAlongAxis = Vector3.Dot(rb.velocity, someAxisInWorldSpace);
```

The above code would give you the velocity along the GameObject's forward axis (the forward velocity).

If the object doesn't have a rigidbody, you can save its old position in a variable and then compare it to the current position in the update loop.

```
Vector3 oldPosition;

private void Start() {
    oldPosition = transform.position;
}

private void Update() {
    Vector3 velocity = transform.position - oldPosition;
    float verticalVelocity = velocity.y / Time.deltaTime; // Divide by dt to get m/s
    oldPosition = transform.position;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for this. I have to add something more. The gameObject that moves up and down has a function. That is, if it moves downwards then the material changes its color to green and if the object moves upwards then the material changes its color to red. Is it possible that I create two gameObjects and check if the moving gameobject is moving towards which 2 gameObjects created so that then the logic applies?

Comment: I am not sure if i am understanding your question correctly here, but you can use the vector between two objects (`Vector3 delta = a.transform.position - b.transform.position`) and use the dot product on that. Does the color changed based on how fast it is moving, or its position on the vertical axis?

Comment: Ok, i read it again, and i think i understand. Let's say that you only use the Y position: `float pos = (transform.position.y - bottomObject.transform.position.y) / (topObject.transform.position.y - bottomObject.transform.position.y)`
This gives you a value between 0 and 1 where 1 is at the top object and 0 is at the bottom object. You can use this to evaluate a gradient with `gradient.Evaluate(pos)`.