# Check if the transform of the object is incrementing or decrementing (without having rigidbody)?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a gameObject that I am moving it manually using mouse (only in one direction - y axis). How do I check in code if the object's transform y value is incrementing or decrementing?

```
if(transform.position.y(isIncrementing))
{
 //do something
//change material
}

else

if(transform.position.y(isDecrementing))
{
 //do something
//change material
}
```

Comment: you'll need to store the position of the object, then the next frame check if the current position is greater or smaller than the position in the previous frame

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to know if the object is moving upward or downward?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55899104/how-to-know-if-the-object-is-moving-upward-or-downward)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I got it.

```
void Start()
{       
    oldPosition.y = Cylinder.transform.position.y;
}

void Update()
{
    if(oldPosition.y > Cylinder.transform.position.y)
    {
        oldPosition.y = Cylinder.transform.position.y;
    }
    if(oldPosition.y < Cylinder.transform.position.y)
    {             
        oldPosition.y = Cylinder.transform.position.y;
    }
}
```